# Perl Readbackwards and gzipped files

Tags: perl, gzip

I want to read backwards line by line from a gzipped file.  I know about the ReadBackwards module, but how do can I make it work on a gzipped file?  Is there a different module I should be using?

Comment: The answers so far have explained why you can't do what you want.  There may be other options; can you provide more details about your actual goal, what sort of things are in the files, why it is that you can't tell how much you need until you see it?  For example, might a two-pass approach work?

Comment: @Poculus - a two pass approach would work.  However, I ended up taking chas' approach.  My problem was that I had very large log files, which contained messages pertaining to several different subject.  For each subject, I need to grab the line immediately before the last line on which some condition (a complicated regex) was true.  This often meant that I needed to read no more than 1-2% of the end of the file, but occasionally, I was reading 10-20% from the bottom and in the worst case I had to up 50% of the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to read it backwards?  There is no performance boost from trying to read a compress file backwards.  You must first decompress it (to understand what byte n means you must first have decompressed bytes 0 .. n).

You probably aren't going to get better in terms of speed than:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

die "usage: $0 filename" unless defined(my $file = shift);

open my $fh, "<:gzip", $file
    or die "could not open $file: $!";

my @lines;
while (<$fh>) {
    push @lines, $_;
    shift @lines if @lines > 10;
}

print @lines;
```

Comment: I don't care if seeking to the end is slow.  What I wanted to avoid was having to store the whole file in memory.  I don't know until I've processed them how many lines I'll need.  I don't, in particular, have a guarantee that I won't need to read the whole file.

Comment: @pythonic metaphor You will need to decompress it to a file and then use `File::Backwards` to read it.

Answer (score 4):

You're pretty much going to need to decompress the file first. You cannot (easily) seek in a gziped file randomly.

Comment: I'm in the situation where the relevant files are quite large, several gb to be precise, and I don't know how many lines I will need to process from the bottom ahead of time.

Comment: @pythonic then there's no way to do what you want that isn't very, very slow. gzip with periodic stream resets is marginally seekable (not from within PerlIO, but you could write code that makes use of it). gzip *without* periodic stream resets is 100% unseekable, and that's probably what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the file in memory. Store it in a SQLite or similar database, with a sequential index field of the line number as it was read and inserted into the database.

When the file is completely stored in the DB walk backwards through the lines by sorting the index using a descending sort. You can quickly jump through the database as necessary, plus you can use database queries to locate lines. It won't be as fast as it would be if you had plenty of RAM or a solid-state drive, but it'll be a heck of a lot faster than trying to process a zipped file like you're talking about.

Computer programming is all about finding creative solutions while working within limitations. You are limited by the RAM and the fact you are working with compressed files. You have to uncompress the file to walk backwards through it, but you can't fit it into RAM. So, you have to put the data somewhere, and that pretty much leaves the disk. It's easier to walk backwards through a database than it is a flat file, so use the database for what it is good for, and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great method for testing this, but from [this post](http://www.dbforums.com/perl-dbi/1617094-how-read-one-line-time-gunzip-file-perl.html) I think you can open the file with

```
open my $handle, '-|', '/usr/bin/gzcat', $filename;
```

This will allow you to step through the file line-by-line as in

```
foreach my $line (<$handle>) {
  do stuff with $line ...
}
```

My understanding is that this doesn't slurp the whole file and should help with memory on the large file. If I am wrong about this hopefully someone will come and slap me with a fish.

I also know that this is going forwards, but my hope for you is that now you won't need to go backwards from a memory standpoint. If you still do perhaps you can do some modification to use it with File::Backwards.

Now, I don't seem to have `gzcat` on my (Ubuntu) system, though I find plenty of references that say that `gzcat` is the same as `zcat` or `gunzip -c` or `gzip -dc` so on the program name YMMV. Again I hope that the method is sound.